# C# Collision Detection with PictureBox

Tags: c#, picturebox, collision

I have a program that adds a picturebox on click in the form, but I want to make sure that the picturebox doesn't overlap with any existing pictureboxes.

Currently I have

```
PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
PB.Name = "Table " + number;
PB.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\table.png");
PB.Size = new Size(65,65);

//x = x + 70;
//y = y + 50;
PB.Location = new Point(LocX, LocY);
PB.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(this.PB_DoubleClick);
foreach (Control picturebox in this.Controls)
{
    if (PB.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picturebox.Bounds))
    {
        //Collision
    }
    else
    {
        this.Controls.Add(PB);
        
    }
}
```

However the controls can still overlap behind one another see:

[image: Overlap example]

Clearly there is something I'm not doing in the code but I can't see what?

Comment: Where have you put this code? And do you want this to happen at *design* time, or *run* time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your foreach is wrong because everytime a picturebox does not intersect you add the new box but another one may do, try something like this instead :

```
bool pBDoIntersect;

 foreach (Control picturebox in this.Controls)
        {
            if (PB.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picturebox.Bounds))
            {
                pBDoIntersect=true;
            }
        }

if(!pBDoIntersect)this.Controls.Add(PB);
```

Comment: I suggest explaining why what OP is doing doesn't work, and how your answer fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I run your changes it doesn't allow me to click anywhere on the form?

Comment: Further to above I believe its because the bool gets set to constantly true if I click within the bounds of the existing item, yet if I use an else to reset it goes back to my original problem?

Comment: What do you mean by don't allow? If you use it more then one time you have to set the bool to false after adding a picturebox